# Unable to Call smart contract in Truffle console

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

I created HelloWorld Smart contract using truffle.
Then I complied and migrated, artificats are generated without any issues.
Then I was able to query HelloWorld.deployed() in truffle console.

Now I have assigned it to a variable.

```
truffle(development)> var helloWorld = HelloWorld.deployed()
```

Problem started after executing the below command and I am unable to proceed.
**

```
truffle(development)> helloWorld.balance.call()
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

**

Looking for your comments to solve and proceed further.
Thanks for your help.

HelloWorld Smart Contract:
naga@naga-VirtualBox:~/ethereum/contracts$ cat HelloWorld.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;


contract HelloWorld {
uint public balance;

function HelloWorld() {
    // constructor
    balance=1000;
  }
}
```

Regards,
Naga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HelloWorld.deployed()` does not give you your smart contract instance.

You can use `helloWorld=HelloWorld.at(HelloWorld.address)` or `HelloWorld.deployed().then(instance => helloWorld=instance)`